# How to stop headphones getting bursts of noise when not playing sound?

Tags: sound

When I connect headphones to my Ubuntu 22.04 system, they make little bursts of noise if there's nothing playing. The noise is hard to describe, but I'd say it's like a rising volume of rising pitch pink noise, short duration, perhaps 1/4 second, that repeats almost at about 2 second intervals. It sounds, with a little imagination, like an old electro-mechanical clock ticking with a kind of bouncing sound (not sure that's really helpful, it's most definitely not a simple "tick" sound!)

It does this even with output level muted (and the volume of the noise doesn't change with output level). I get no such noise from the laptop's speakers, and if there is sound playing (so far as I can tell from any source) then the signal is clean.

I'm using whatever sound system is default for 22.04, but am of course happy to provide more details if you tell me how to find that info.

What gives? Can I stop this?